# Difference between "String" and "string" in .NET and which is best?

Tags: c#, .net

In the .NET Framework, at least in the C# language, we have two "versions" of the string type:

- "string"
- "String"

It appears that they are interchangeable, but are they really?  If they are not interchangeable, is it generally better to use one instead of the other, and under what circumstances?

Comment: Similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6000517/6504

Comment: Stylistically, I tend to use the lower-case version when I'm referring to the type, and the upper-case version when I'm calling a static method of System.String.

Comment: Identical to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/in-c-sharp-what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-string.

Comment: `string` does not exist in `.net`, it only exists in C#.

Comment: Although this might be a bit more suitable for Stack Overflow, I don't think it's completely off topic for Programmers, and since Stack Overflow already has at least one duplicate there wouldn't be much point in migrating this. So please stop flagging / close voting to migrate, if you feel this should be closed, that's cool, but it should be closed not migrated.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Well according to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx)

> **string** is an alias for [String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) in the .NET Framework.

Where "String" is in fact `System.String`.

I would say that they are interchangeable and there is no difference when and where you should use one or the other.

It would be better to be consistent with which one you did use though.

Comment: for some reason I had it in my head that String was a class wrapper around a value typed string and this leads to the idea of boxing... am i totally wrong here?

Comment: @Gabriel No, `String` (and hence `string` by alias) are reference types.

Comment: @Gabriel: doesn't Java do that with stuff like byte vs Byte?

Comment: Is the same also true for Double vs double, and other data types?

Comment: @GavinCoates - [yes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: @AaronAnodide I believe that's a Java convention, which is probably where you heard of it.

Comment: @ChrisF correct me if I'm saying something wrong: string/String is reference type and double/Double is value type.

Answer (score 22):

As pointed out, they are the same thing and `string` is just an alias to `String`.

For what it's worth, I use `string` to declare types - variables, properties, return values and parameters. This is consistent with the use of other system types - `int`, `bool`, `var` etc (although `Int32` and `Boolean` are also correct).

I use `String` when using the static methods on the String class, like `String.Split()` or `String.IsNullOrEmpty()`. I feel that this makes more sense because the methods belong to a class, and it is consistent with how I use other static methods.

Comment: We use this convention at work as well, and I like it. My brain automatically makes the connection.

Comment: I have always done the same or the same reason. Glad I'm not the only one. Annoyed how Visual Studio now suggests (nags) changing `String` to `string` is "simplifying".

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest using lowercase `string`.  Uppercase `String` will use the first class named String it finds in the imported namespaces ... which is generally `System.String`.  It's possible for your own String class to be used instead.

Comment: If you have two different imported types with the same name, and you use that name without namespace qualification, you will get an error.

Comment: It's possible to trick `String` into working, it's never possible to trick `string`.

Comment: Still, I don't think that's a good enough reason to use `string`.

Comment: How is "one might break" vs. "one will never break" with all else being identical not a good enough reason?

Answer (score 4):

**`string` is a C# keyword which is simply an alias for the `System.String`**

..but as it's a keyword, your syntax colouring editor/IDE will show it in keyword colour, same as int, double, if, else, etc. Stylistically, you may prefer to use the keyword rather than the `System.String` type (or just `String` after you've done `using System;`).

This is a niche point though, as although `bool`, `char`, `int`, `double` and `string` are all keyword aliases for system types, `string` is an odd-one-out as it is a reference type and the others are value types.

Comment: `object` is a keyword alias for a reference type, too

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot all about that one - thanks for reminder.

Answer (score 2):

`string` is just an alias for `String`, they're ultimately the same.

You can use whichever you prefer, although I generally use `string` when I'm planning on using it much like a primitive data type (similar to `int`, `float`, or `bool`) and `String` when I'm planning on using it as an object/class. For example:

```
string foo = "   ";
if (String.isNullOrWhitespace(foo)) 
{
    // ...
}
```

In the case above, I'm planning on using `foo` simply to store some text (effectively as a primitive), so I use `string`; however, when I call `String.isNullOrWhitespace(string)` I use `String`. I do this, because generally the first letter of class names are capitalized (`String`) while the first letter of primitives (such as `int`) are not.

Answer (score -2):

String is used with namespace System.String, string is used C# compiler specification, moreover **System.String** is reference type value. You are preferred to deal with System objects, string for literals purposes only. System and system both working is same.

```
string TC = new System.String('/', 5);
```

String is used for comparing, equal and other purposes as well.

Comment: this doesn't seem to offer anything substantial over prior 6 answers